# Does else cost anything CPU cycles wise?

Tags: c, cpu-usage

I have 2 examples:

```
if (i mod [number] == 0)
      do thing;
else 
      do other thing
```

and

```
if (i mod [number] != 0)
       do other thing;
else
       do thing
```

Are these 2 examples equal CPU cycles wise?

Comment: Build with optimizations enabled and look at the generated code. A decent compiler could generate the same code for both.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Depends on your CPU. I highly doubt that the optimized code has any difference at all, but you never know. There are some legendarily awful C compilers out there. In general do the *simplest* thing that works and *only* optimize if you have a *measurable* performance problem.

Comment: This is something that is going to vary based on the compiler and the architecture it's built for, but it will probably always be the same. And more importantly, not something you should be overly concerned about. Focus on readability/maintainability rather than trying to save 1 cycle

Comment: To find out how many CPU cycles it takes, you need to look at the final assembler code.  Even having the final code it is not all the time easy.  For an approximation one can use  the big omega analysis but the real experts use analytic combinatorics to predict the average time of execution.

Comment: If `thing` and `other thing` are amenable to it, you could look into using a `branchless` paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

In C you don't write CPU instructions. You write instructions for an abstract C machine. The compiler then transforms your C code into CPU code and it has the freedom to generate any CPU code as long as it keeps the observable behavior of your C program. Since both code snippets are equivalent, both can generate the same assembly code. Don't invert if condition for the sake of performance because it's futile.

A real optimization you can do here is use the [`[[likely]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely) hint to the compiler. Most compilers have their own C non-standard equivalent. Be aware that this optimization doesn't "save cycles" in the way you think about it. Rather it can help with [pipeline branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) in  certain pattern usage scenarios. Optimization is a very deep and interesting field if you want to go that rabbit hole. It's not as simple as it might appear. Also if this is not hot code any optimization here will have practically no effect. So always first profile profile profile.

First write clean clear code. Then profile and if you find a problem then go in and try optimizations based on what the profiling showed. Don't do [premature optimizations](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).